# How to delete local computer files in the ftp session with a file. scr?

Tags: session, batch-file, ftp, dos

I have a .bat file (**test.bat**) :

```
ftp -s:Test_DOWN.scr
pause
```

I have a .scr file (**Test_DOWN.scr**) :

```
open ftp01.citobi.be
USERNAME
PASSWORD
prompt n
mput *.csv
quit
cd C:\...
del *.csv
```

The problem is that I want to remove files in my directory C:... but when I execute **test.bat**, it doesn't execute the last two lines.

I want to know if it is possible to run these two lines in the same script after ftp commands?

ps : When I launch prompt command from start --> run --> cmd and I connect to ftp. The `quit` ftp command works well, I pass the ftp session to host session. But with the .bat file, after `quit`command, it's over..

Comment: Isn't scr the extension for screensaver?

Comment: @Eun Yes, I followed here [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555976/en-us]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem...

I used **!** ftp command (escape to the shell).

```
!del *.csv
```

And it works well.